# How can I "stick" a control on top edge of screen?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

I have a custom control which shows some statistic data and need always be placed at the top edge of WP7 screen. but, when user inputs something on a textbox, the soft-keyboard popup. And   the custom control is moved out of the screen. I want to make sure the custom control always visible, even when soft keyboard is popup. Does anyone know how to do  this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must to use some "magic". By "magic" I mean [RenderTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransform.aspx).

Solution is simple - you need to move your custom control (down, when keyboard visible; up, when hidden). 
 Check [this valuable post](http://sorokoletov.com/2011/08/windows-phone-70-handling-text-entry-screens/) - it's must help you.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="Test.Keyboard.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape"
    >
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock Text="WINDOWS PHONE" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="developer's ?" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0"></Grid>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" LostFocus="TextBoxLostFocus"/>
    </Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>




public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        private const double LandscapeShift = -259d;
        private const double LandscapeShiftWithBar = -328d;
        private const double Epsilon = 0.00000001d;
        private const double PortraitShift = -339d;
        private const double PortraitShiftWithBar = -408d;

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TranslateYProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TranslateY", typeof(double), typeof(MainPage), new PropertyMetadata(0d, OnRenderXPropertyChanged));

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += MainPageLoaded;
        }

        public double TranslateY
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(TranslateYProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TranslateYProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void OnRenderXPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((MainPage)d).UpdateTopMargin((double)e.NewValue);
        }

        private void MainPageLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            BindToKeyboardFocus();
        }

        private void BindToKeyboardFocus()
        {
            PhoneApplicationFrame frame = Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame;
            if (frame != null)
            {
                var group = frame.RenderTransform as TransformGroup;
                if (group != null)
                {
                    var translate = group.Children[0] as TranslateTransform;
                    var translateYBinding = new Binding("Y");
                    translateYBinding.Source = translate;
                    SetBinding(TranslateYProperty, translateYBinding);
                }
            }
        }

        private void UpdateTopMargin(double translateY)
        {
            if (IsClose(translateY, LandscapeShift) || IsClose(translateY, PortraitShift)
||IsClose(translateY, LandscapeShiftWithBar) || IsClose(translateY, PortraitShiftWithBar)
)
            {
                LayoutRoot.Margin = new Thickness(0, -translateY, 0, 0);
            }
        }

        private bool IsClose(double a, double b)
        {
            return Math.Abs(a - b) < Epsilon;
        }

        private void TextBoxLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            LayoutRoot.Margin = new Thickness();
        }
    }
```

**Good Luck....**